# Custom Resolution on Raspberry Pi 4 (640x1080)

Tags: hdmi

I have a samsung professional display, currently magic server is splitting the screen into thirds. On one third I have the input set as hdmi. To which I want to display my raspberry pi 4 on.

The display has an overall resolution of 1920 by 1080. Which leaves the raspberry pi with 640x1080.

The problem is that the image looks distorted (horizontally flattened), everything looks skinny.

I have tried modifying the resolution using raspi-config. I have tried changing framebuffer and other hdmi settings in /boot/config.txt but the image always looks distorted (horizontally flattened)

Some of the values I have tried is to set the frame buffer and hdmi-cvt to 1920x1080 and 640x1080